# Winforms: ComboBox height doesn't resize when resolution is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a basic combobox in a form. Compared to other controls(Button,label, etc) the height of the combobox doesn't change when the resolution is changed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string result;
    string fontInformation;

    private bool scaleFactorKnown = false;
    private SizeF scaleFactor;
    public Form1()
    {
        SizeChanged += Form1_SizeChanged;
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Location = new Point(12, 36);
        label1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        label1.Scale(scaleFactor);

        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        textBox1.Location = new Point(133, 33);
        textBox1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        textBox1.Scale(scaleFactor);

        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 

        comboBox1.Location = new Point(250, 33);
        comboBox1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        comboBox1.Scale(scaleFactor);
        // button1
        // 
        button1.Location = new Point(365, 32);
        button1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        button1.Scale(scaleFactor);
        // 
        // radioButton1
        // 

        radioButton1.Location = new Point(480, 32);
        radioButton1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        radioButton1.Scale(scaleFactor);
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        checkBox1.Location = new Point(586, 33);
        checkBox1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        checkBox1.Scale(scaleFactor);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 

        textBox2.Location = new Point(26, 102);
        textBox2.Size = new Size(660, 250);
        textBox2.Scale(scaleFactor);

    }

   private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!scaleFactorKnown)
        {
            scaleFactor = AutoScaleFactor;
            scaleFactorKnown = true;
        }
        Size controlSize = new Size((int)(comboBox1.Width * scaleFactor.Width),
           (int)(comboBox1.Height * scaleFactor.Height)); //use for sizing


        //set bounds
        comboBox1.Bounds = new Rectangle(comboBox1.Location, controlSize);

    }
}
```

I have tried the method Scale() to scale all other controls, it works for other controls except for combobox. I also tried manually changing the bound but it didn't work. I also tried change the anchor and dock as well.

1. Expected result: Combobox height(At 150%)=42
2. Actual result: Combobox
       height(At 150%)=28

Would appreciate any help on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [`IntegralHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.integralheight(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `ComboBox` to `false`:

```
    comboBox1.Location = new Point(250, 33);
    comboBox1.Size = new Size(100, 21);
    comboBox1.Scale(scaleFactor);
    comboBox1.IntegralHeight = false;
```